# How to create InMemoryUploadedFile objects proper in django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, io, python-imaging-library

I'm using a python function to resize user uploaded images in Django. I use `BytesIO()` and `InMemoryUploadedFile()` classes to convert `pillow` object to Django `UplodedFile` and save it in the model.
here how I instantiate `InMemoryUploadedFile` object

```
from PIL import Image
import io
import PIL
import sys
from django.core.files.uploadedfile import InMemoryUploadedFile


def image_resize(image,basewidth):
    img_io = io.BytesIO()
    img = Image.open(image)
    percent = (basewidth / float(img.size[0]))
    hsize = int(float(img.size[1]) * percent)
    img = img.resize((basewidth, hsize),PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS)
      
    img.save(img_io, format="JPEG")
        
    new_pic= InMemoryUploadedFile(img_io, 
            'ImageField',
            'profile_pic',
            'JPEG',
            sys.getsizeof(img_io), None)
    return new_pic
```

but this resize the image and it does not save the file as a jpeg it saves the file with the type of File
but when to replace the filename with `profile_pic.jpg` it saves with the type of jpeg.
why this happens

Comment: Could you include the code for the  ```img``` variable initialization?

Comment: sorry, I have missed one line

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `field_name` parameter in `InMemoryUploadedFile(file, field_name, name, content_type, size, charset)` requires the full filename including the file extension for reasons the [official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/_modules/django/core/files/uploadedfile/#InMemoryUploadedFile) does not list. [Here is a link](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/54371/django.core.files.uploadedfile.InMemoryUploadedFile) giving some sample usage of `InMemoryUploadedFile` (look at example 8)

Getting the file extension should be easy when using `os.path.splitext` like so:

```
def image_resize(image,basewidth):
    img_io = io.BytesIO()
    img = Image.open(image)
    img_ext = list(os.path.splitext(img.filename))[-1]
    percent = (basewidth / float(img.size[0]))
    hsize = int(float(img.size[1]) * percent)
    img = img.resize((basewidth, hsize),PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS)
    img.save(img_io, format="JPEG")
        
    new_pic= InMemoryUploadedFile(img_io, 
            'ImageField',
            'profile_pic' + img_ext,
            'JPEG',
            sys.getsizeof(img_io), None)
    return new_pic
```

Comment: The official documentation is lamentable on this